# I want to replace the parent page with the content of the IFrame if/when the content comes from a different domain

Tags: javascript, html

I have an iframe that contains links to other websites. I cannot easily change the "target" of these links. as soon as the user clicks a link that leads off of the current domain, I want to "remove" the iframe. That is, I want the content of the iframe to become the whole page, and the "old" parent page to simply be ignored.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You want that when user click iframe the iframe will be on the whole page and old content will be hidden?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the iframe load event and change the window's location based on that.

With jQuery:

```
$('iframe').load(function(){
    window.location = $(this).attr('src') ;
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/qf8mj/)